# Changing raw pointers to smart in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, smart-pointers

There is a simple function creating an zero-filled matrix stored in array.

```
void zeroMatrix(const int rows, const int columns, void* M)
{
   for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
       for(int j = 0; j < columns; j++)
          *(((double *)M) + (rows * i) + j) = 0;

}
```

How do I change the code to use `std::unique_ptr<double>` as M?

Comment: Why is `M` a `void*` at the moment?

Comment: You do not need `unique_ptr` inside function, only outside. Because your function does not hold ownershib of matrix

Comment: @sftrabbit Trying to use it for some other types as well as for double.

Comment: If you want to use it for other types as well, you could use a template. Then you don't have to cast to double. Also, you are creating a raw pointer, which you are using as an array. I wouldn't use a unique_ptr for that, but rather a std::vector (or std::array since you are using c++11 and the size of a matrix won't change).

Comment: this function is pretty bad, are you using it?

Comment: @neagoegab Not really, it's an example. Also, any advices are welcome.

Comment: memset, std::vector with fill constructor, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since there is no ownership transfer to the `zeroMatrix` function, what you need is a *reference*:

(Assuming M is a vector)

```
void zeroMatrix(const int rows, const int columns, std::vector<double> &M)
{
   for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
       for(int j = 0; j < columns; j++)
          M[(rows * i) + j] = 0;

}
```

Comment: Keep in mind, though, that this is merely for the sake of the example and that there are much better ways to set all elements in a vector (or an array thereof) to 0.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Can you add one of these better ways examples to your answer, please?

Comment: @PavelOganesyan That's quite irrelevant to the question, so I'll post it here: `M = std::vector<double>(M.size());`